# Fetch data from multiple related tables using Entity Framework core and display in view in Asp.Net Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am working on one Asp.Net Core application using Entity Framework Core. That app is basically into E Commerce. I want to fetch information of particular product from multiple tables which are related to each other using the master table product, and then i want to pass the data to the View. Can anyone help me in this regard. I am unable to find any perfect solution of Joins and pass the related data to View.

Comment: No details. What is the problem? source code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/

Answer (score 2):

To complete these steps you need Visual Studio 2022.

Based on current documentation:

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderDetailID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

It is a very simple model which contains only two classes, Order and OrderDetail has a one-to-many relationship. The next step is to add a new context class and make sure to inherit from the **DbContext** class

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=StoreDB;");
    }
}
```

Now to create a database using migrations from your model, install the following packages;

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

Once these packages are installed, run the following command in Package Manager Console.

```
Add-Migration Initial
```

This command scaffold a migration to create the initial set of tables for your model. When it is executed successfully, then run the following command.

```
Update-Database to apply the new migration to the database. This command creates the database before applying migrations.
```

If you need to learn how to set up relationships the following websites have very good documentation and walkthrough on the entity framework.

I hope the following links help:

https://entityframeworkcore.com
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution, It can be help someone else. As Its 4 year old question, and it was already implemented.

Comment: @MohammedAltaf I agree. The entity Framework has come a long way. With convention over configuration, it is easier to focus on the business model of the system a programmer is developing...this way, we can meet project delivery timelines.